# Get meta information for selected columns from PostgreSQL using PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

is there a way of getting table name for each column in a postgre result in PHP?

Imagine you have a select with join, for example:

```
$Q = <<<E2OD
    SELECT * FROM user U
    LEFT JOIN department D ON U.department_id = D.id
E2OD;
```

In PHP/FirebirdSQL:

```
$R = ibase_query($Q);
$D = ibase_fetch_row($R);
$info = ibase_field_info($R, 0);
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [name] => id
    [1] => id
    [alias] => id
    [2] => user
    [relation] => user
    [3] => 8
    [length] => 8
    [4] => BIGINT
    [type] => BIGINT
)
```

While in PHP/PostgreSQL:

```
$select = $DB->query($Q);
$meta = $select->getColumnMeta(0);
```

Returns

```
Array
(
    [pgsql:oid] => 20
    [native_type] => int8
    [name] => id
    [len] => 8
    [precision] => -1
    [pdo_type] => 2
)
```

As you see, there's no information about the table the column is from. There's a missing key `[relation] => user` or similar displaying the table name.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php

Can PHP get this information with it's PG or PDO libraries? Does PostgreSQL provide this information to client libraries? What needs to be done to make this happen?

Thanks for any hint,

Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [pg_field_table()](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-field-table.php).

Comment: Thanks Frank. I searched manuals but couldn't find it. It turned out that my local .chm help file was almost up to date but... a bit outdated :)